# Zabbix. Maintenance status while deploying

Tags: jenkins, monitoring, zabbix

There are Zabbix for monitoring and Jenkins for deployment. Is it possible to change hosts statuses from Enable to Maintenance automatically during  deploying process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zabbix API and create or update maintenance periods as needed: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/api/maintenance .

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Using Zabbix API is a great idea but not in my case. We don't have deploying schedule so I'll have to set maintenance status manually. I'm trying to find the way to automate this process.

Comment: The API suggestion was meant to use the API to dynamically update maintenance periods (time windows, hosts and groups that are part of the maintenance etc).

Comment: I've added a maintenace period to zabbix through the API.

Now if there was just a way to circumvent the fact that zabbix will only enable maintenance periods on every minute... some of my deployments take shorter than that.

Zabbix has an internal timer that evaluates maintenance periods and there's no way to force it to run.

Comment: That is correct. Maintenance status is evaluated every minute at second 0, this is hardcoded.